# Converting MySQL to MS Access

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access

I have a table in MySQL with a large amount of data that I would really rather not manually copy accross to MS Access. In simple terms how would I convert the Table from MySQL to the MS Access.

Thanks in advance!

S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to use ODBC. Use Access to pull in the data from MySQL.

- Install the [MySQL ODBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/).
- Create a system DSN for the MySQL database.
- Create a new Access database.
- Find the approprate Access menu command for importing external data. This will depend on your version of Access. A2010 has a ribbon menu called "External Data".
- select the ODBC data source (Machine Data Source) using the DSN you created.
- select the tables you need, and proceed with the import.

[image]

Comment: @p: Does that require MySQL to be running on Windows?

Comment: @Eric: I haven't tested this with non-Windows endpoints. That ODBC is cross-platform, I'd guess that it's supported, but obviously some testing is required. Haven't done it myself.

Comment: MySQL should not have to be running on Windows for this to work. Both of the answers you got so far are good solutions in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your input, I shall try it now and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I was able to import the data using these instructions, but the relationships between tables are lost.

Answer (score 3):

One simple approach is to export the table to CSV format from MySQL and import it into Access from CSV using the data import wizard.

MySQL to CSV

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-export-data-csv/

CSV to Access

http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/27511.aspx

Comment: Thanks Eric appreciate your input!